# Kubernetes the hard way, how different to production like kubernetes cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm

I am learning about kubernetes clusters and tried two alternatives to create the cluster. [Kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/) and [Kubernetes the hard way](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way).

I see the following description in the repository of kubernetes the hard way:

```
Kubernetes The Hard Way is optimized for learning, which means taking the long route to
 ensure you understand each task required to bootstrap a Kubernetes cluster.

The results of this tutorial should not be viewed as production ready,
and may receive limited support from the community, but don't let that stop you from learning!
```

But when I create the same cluster with the two alternatives I don't see the differences in between the two clusters. The end result of the two of them is the same besides the fact that with Kubeadm I have to install it in the corresponding nodes to be able to use it, and in many cases commands like "init" made a lot of things automatically.

I understand that Kubernetes the hard way is longer, with purpose of education and a lot manual steps. But I don't understand why it is not production ready?

**Does anyone knows which are the differences in between a kubernetes cluster generated with kubeadm and the steps followed by Kubernetes the hard way?**

Please don't consider this as a preference of one method on top of another, is just to understand a bit more of possible differences of what I learnt with the kubernetes the hard way and a cluster generated with kubeadm.